# Closed form for series involving harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

Is there a closed form for this series values:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{H_k^{(n)}}{k}
$$

where

$$
H_k^{(n)}=\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{i^n}
$$

and n is a positive integer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In [this paper](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/db90/pdfs/db90-107.00.pdf) we have some identities for $$\alpha_{h}\left(s,t\right)=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k^{t}}H_{k-1}^{\left(s\right)}
 $$ (for some special value of $s
 $ and $t
 $) which can be rewritten as $$\alpha_{h}\left(s,t\right)=\left(1-2^{1-s-t}\right)\zeta\left(s+t\right)+\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k^{t}}H_{k}^{\left(s\right)}.
 $$