# Limit of infinite series involving harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

The $k^{th}$ harmonic number is given as
\begin{equation} H_{k} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{i} \end{equation}

I am interested in the following series:
\begin{equation} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_{k} \right)^{-k}}{k!} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

and for some real positive (possibly integer) $\lambda$:
\begin{equation} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\lambda^k \left(H_{k} \right)^{-k}}{k!} \tag{2} \end{equation}

According to [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20Harmonic%28k%29%5E%28-k%29%2Fk%21%20from%20k%3D1%20to%20infinity), $\left( 1 \right)$ is convergent to some expression, which (taking terms in the sum), is something like $1 + \frac{2}{9} + \frac{36}{11^3} + ...$ , while $\left( 2 \right)$ also appears to converge for [some](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%203%5Ek%20Harmonic%28k%29%5E%28-k%29%2Fk%21%20from%20k%3D1%20to%20infinity) $\lambda \in \mathbb{N}$ that I have tried.

What I want for Christmas is to know how to determine the limit of the sum in $\left( 2 \right)$ in terms of $\lambda $, or even an upper bound. As a starting point, I tried to work out the analytic limit of the sum in $\left( 1 \right)$ but failed.

This is similar to other questions [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298589/closed-form-for-series-involving-harmonic-numbers),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294486/a-series-involving-harmonic-numbers), except with the factorial of $k$ and not quite using the generalised harmonic numbers $\left( H_{k,n} \ne {\left(H_{k}\right)}^{n} \right)$

Comment: I would not expect a nice closed form. We can deal with fixed powers of the harmonic numbers in the coefficients, hardly we can do the same with $H_k^k$.

Comment: Thanks -  you are probably right, but I figured I would ask anyway.

Comment: Series (2) converges for all real (even complex) $\lambda$. Its sum is bounded in modulus by $e^{|\lambda|}$.